# Variables in the for Loop

Tags: javascript, variables, for-loop

```js
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];
var text = "33";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
text += cars[i] + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Hi, I want a better understanding of JavaScript and I'm confused about this variable in the for loop. Why does the result not add the value of text in each result in the set?

```
33bmw
Volvo
Saab
Ford
```

why is it not this..

```
33bmw
33Volvo
33Saab
33Ford
```

Comment: `text += cars[i] + "<br>"` is the same as `text = text + cars[i] + "<br>"`, so the string keeps getting longer from the end, and you're mutating the same variable with only the new data.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy this has absolutely nothing to do with the `<br>`.

Comment: Side note: A quicker way would be: `"33" + cars.join("<br>33") + "<br>"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer in comments in code**

```js
//array of strings
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];
// sets the variable text to "33"
var text = "33";
var i;
// loops through the strings in cars variable
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    // adds car string + <br> to text
    // first pass is 33BMW<br>
    // second pass is 33BMW<br>Volvo<br> 
    // third pass is 33BMW<br>Volvo<br>Saab<br>
    // fourth pass is 33BMW<br>Volvo<br>Saab<br>Ford<br>
    text += cars[i] + "<br>";
}

// writes the text to an html element
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

**Solution**
Create a prefix of `33` then append it in the loop so it is on every single line

```js
//array of strings
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];
var text = "";
var prefix = "33";
var i;
// loops through the strings in cars variable
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    text += prefix + cars[i] + "<br>";
}

// writes the text to an html element
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for a clear answer.. I get now after reading this like 3 times thanks!!

Comment: @user1119742 not a problem, to test this in the future I highly recommend using the debugger built into firefox/chrome/IE/safari.  With this you can step one line at a time and see what `text` is equal to.  Debugging is a great way to coming to complete understanding of something.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you add every `cars` item to `text`. And after first iteration `text` is no more just `33`. Its `33BMW`.

What you need is:

```
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];
var text = "33";
var result = "";  // add a special variable to store both `text` and `car` name
var i;
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    result += text + cars[i] + "<br>";  // use it here
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;   // and here
```

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing *text* to "33". And then for each car you are appending the name of the car (car[i]) and br to text. What you want is to initialize text to "". And then for each car, append "33".

```
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    text += "33" + cars[i] + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

Answer (score 0):

This would give you the result you want:

```
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];
var prefix = "33";
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
text += prefix  + cars[i] + "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];
var text = "33";
var output;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
output += (text + cars[i]) + "<br>";
}
```

should be your code. text = text + cars[0] creates 33BMW. The next iteration appends Volvo to 33BMW not 33Volvo to 33BMW.

Answer (score 0):

You have to concat text in every value of cars.

[Answer jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/L9q3mz0x/1/)

**New Script**

```
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];
var text = "33";
var out_text = '';

out_text = cars.map(function(i){
    return text + i;
}).join( "<br/>");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = out_text;
```

**Your Script:**

```
var cars = ["BMW", "Volvo", "Saab", "Ford"];
var text = "33";
var i; 
var out_text = '';
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    out_text = text + cars[i] + "<br>";
}
```

**Output:**

> 33BMW
>   33Volvo
>   33Saab
>   33Ford

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = out_text;
```

Comment: you need to declare `var out_text = ""` or this will fail